# Why does Palpatine consider Vader as a part of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

If Palpatine intended to replace the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two) with the [Rule of One](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_One_(Palpatine%27s_Doctrine)), where he will rule forever with many dark acolytes, then why isn't Vader just one of them, but is considered instead as a true Sith?

Comment: First I've heard of this "Rule of One", hmmm

Comment: Just because Palpatine intends to reorganize the order doesn't mean the current Sith are not true Sith. You are an employee at the company you work for until you are fired.

Comment: Well, see, Palpatine intended to replace the Rule of Two long ago, especially since he concluded that the Rule will have served its purpose once the Jedi are exterminated. A new Rule is needed, and he decided on the philosophy to be called the Rule of One. It's not something he thought of after Anakin became his apprentice. It started long before. So...he can accept Anakin as an apprentice without inducting him into the Sith Order, which would be more aligned with his new Rule. So why is Anakin made Sith if there's no longer a need nor intent to? He can just be First Acolyte or something.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I'm sure there's a line in the film where Palpatine says Vader will become more powerful than he could ever imagine, essentially taking the mantle. Maybe Palpatine's agenda was above and beyond his own life, and he was willing to sacrifice himself for the greater "good" of the Sith Order becoming stronger and more powerful.

Comment: In fact I found it. It's a line within the Skirmish in the Senate between Yoda and Palpatine. He says "Lord Vader will become more powerful than either of us". Suggesting that he'd already resigned to the fact that one day Vader will be numero uno. Maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: Hmm, but if the Jedi no longer exists and if Palpatine simply doesn't tell Anakin everything about the dark side...can be really? Raw power, yes, but in actual battle, even if Mustafar didn't happen...

Comment: As I understand Palpatine's Rule of One, there are multiple apprentices considered Sith but only *one* ruler (the Dark Lord of the Sith, Palpatine himself). Vader would have been just another apprentice (albeit probably the strongest) but would still have been Sith.

Answer (score 2):

In current canon, Darth Sidious is shown to be more accepting of and believing in The Rule of Two than his legends counter part(which is where the Rule of One concept comes from).

In Legends Palpatine only wanted Anakin as an Apprentice when he was fully Human(or i guess ~90% human because of his Robo-hand) and after Obi-Wan dismantled Anakin on Mustafar, Vader became damaged goods. He could no longer surpass Palpatine because the force could no longer flow through Vader properly.

In Canon, because the force still flows through Vader unhindered, even with the Robo-limbs, Palpatine is still willing to train Vader to be his Successor.

In Legends it was very rare to see Palpatine approve of anything Vader does, because to Palpatine, Vader is nothing more than an attack dog. As such Palpatine decided that only One Person was fit to rule his Empire, Himself. He never intended Post-Suit Vader to surpass and Destroy him. The Rule of Two ends with Palpatine and its now the Rule of One.

It should also be noted that the Rule of One and Darth Krayt's One Sith are two different Ideas. Palpatine's Rule of One is simply "There is only a Single Sith Lord(A True Darth), Me.". But The One Sith are more "We are all Dark Lords of the Sith, but We all serve Darth Krayt," If anything The Rule of One is a logical end to the lineage of Darth Bane's Rule of Two. Meanwhile The One Sith are more like Lord Kaan's Brotherhood of Darkness. All are equal under the Brotherhood, just Kaan is a bit more equal than everyone else.

TL;DR: In Legends, Palpatine hates Vader for losing and becoming a cripple, so he intends to become basically an Immortal Emperor who will rule the Galaxy for ever, by himself. In Canon, because Vader is still able to surpass Palpatine in terms of Force Ability, Palpatine continues the Rule of Two and expects that some day, Vader will kill him and take The Throne of The Empire and The Sith for himself.

Answer (score 0):

Everything Palpatine did in episodes 1-6 had gone according to plan, except Vader needing the suit, which he did not expect. Palpy planned to make Anakin his apprentice since TPM. Notice how after ROTS Vader became the face of the Empire, while Palpatine became a recluse. For proof, the Moff on Death Star 2 was shocked and horrified when told the Emperor was coming. Also Palpatine no longer used his Sith name after the prequels. Palpatine planned to let the galaxy know the Sith were in charge without outing himself.

Comment: BTW, the Rule of One was in Star Wars Legends. Ex-Jedi Darth Krayt founded it after the Empire's fall. It was like the ancient Sith: many servants under one leader.

Comment: as far as I know even in canon it is hinted that Palpatine wanted to rule and not die at an apprentices hand thus subverting the rule of two and making a rule of one instead.